# View vs Sub-Query; filtering for a window function output

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, sql-view

I am a bit confused as I am trying to use the lead window function to get the most recent load_time_stamp to become the effective_to column. That being said, it works as I expect when I check for a test record using a subquery, but when I create the view and query the view with the filter -- I get all the same values for effective_to column.

what does not work:

```
create or replace  view window_view
  
   as (



WITH window_view AS (
    SELECT
        t1.*,
        t1.load_timestamp AS effective_from,
        LEAD(t1.load_timestamp) OVER (
            PARTITION BY t1.account_hash_id
            ORDER BY
                t1.load_timestamp
        ) AS effective_to
    FROM
        base_table t1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    window_view
  );

select EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO  from window_view

where ID = '234';
```

What does work:

```
WITH window_view AS (
    SELECT
        t1.*,
        t1.load_timestamp AS effective_from,
        LEAD(t1.load_timestamp) OVER (
            PARTITION BY t1.account_hash_id
            ORDER BY
                t1.load_timestamp
        ) AS effective_to
    FROM
       base_table t1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    window_view 
    where id = '234'
  ;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data  to reproduce the case in form of `CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO`

Comment: Have you tried re-running after fixing your original question, which created a view called `SANDBOX_PSOULAGES.mart.es_organization_account_test`

Comment: yes I did and same results

Comment: Difficult to be sure without sample data and the results your 2 queries give, but your 2 queries aren’t the same. A CTE is part of the overall SQL and it all executes as one item - the CTE is just an easier way to write a complex query. So your second query will filter the data on ID = '234' and then run the window function. The view will run the window function on all your data and then subsequent query will filter the view resultset using ID = '234'

Comment: Maybe your namespace is conflicting? Have you tried renaming your `window_view` CTE to something else?